# Bazaar Eclipse or External Merge/Conflicts Tool

Tags: eclipse, svn, bazaar

Are there any good tools for merging/resolving conflicts for Bazaar + Eclipse?

I wish Bazaar was integrated with Eclipse the same way Subversion is.

Comment: I wish subversion was integrated with eclipse the way cvs is. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Bzr-Eclipse](https://launchpad.net/bzr-eclipse) and [QBzr-Eclipse](https://launchpad.net/qbzr-eclipse/)?  I think it's an either-or choice: don't install both.  Bzr-Eclipse uses it's own interface, so it looks closer to the Eclipse way of doing things.  QBzr-Eclipse links in to QBzr's dialog boxes, so it looks like Bazaar Explorer and is probably better maintained ([this link](http://javierder.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/bzreclipse-unofficial-release/)).  I prefer QBzr-Eclipse, but it's up to you: try them both and see how you get on.

There are some Bzr Eclipse screenshots [here](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrEclipse/Screenshots).

Comment: Bzr Eclipse seems supported by canonical : http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrEclipse but it doesn't handle every protocol.

Comment: bzr eclipse isn't supported by Canonical, it was an external project. I don't think it's maintained actively at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

## Install & Configure

1. Root access.

   sudo su
2. Install *meld*:

   apt-get install meld
3. Go to "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/plugins":

   cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/plugins
4. Download **ExtMerge Bazaar Plugin**:

   bzr branch lp:bzr-extmerge extmerge
5. Create merge script: "/usr/bin/meld-helper":

   vim /usr/bin/meld-helper
6. Write content for merge script:

   #!/bin/bash

   mv $1 $1.bak

   mv $3 $1

   meld $2 $4 $1

   mv $1 $3

   mv $1.bak $1

   exit 0
7. Exit from root user.

   exit
8. Go to Bazaar home path: "~/.bazaar/".

   cd ~/.bazaar/
9. Make configuration backup.

   cp bazaar.conf bazaar.conf.bak
10. Edit Bazaar configuration file.

    vim bazaar.conf
11. Add follow line at the end (before "[ALIASES]" line, check if exists first, and change it):

    external_merge = 'meld-helper %r %b %t %o'
12. Finish!

## Usage

### Using "*checkout*"

1. Commit changes:

   bzr commit -m "COMMIT DESCRIPTION"
2. Update project:

   bzr update
3. Merge conflicts:

   bzr extmerge test-file.txt
4. Mark as resolved:

   bzr resolve test-file.txt
5. Commit changes:

   bzr commit -m "COMMIT DESCRIPTION"
6. Finish!

### Using "*branch*"

1. Commit changes:

   bzr commit -m "COMMIT DESCRIPTION"
2. Get changes:

   bzr pull
3. Merge changes:

   bzr merge
4. Merge conflicts:

   bzr extmerge test-file.txt
5. Mark as resolved:

   bzr resolve test-file.txt
6. Commit changes:

   bzr commit -m "COMMIT DESCRIPTION"
7. Send changes:

   bzr push
8. Finish!

## Notes

In "meld", you have 3 columns:

1. *test.txt **.BASE*** : Is the first version of file, in last "update" or "pull".
2. *test.txt **.OTHER*** : Is new version of file in the server.
3. ***test.txt*** : Is your local version. In this file is where I save the changes to "commit".

**Your merged file is "test.txt", when you close " *meld* "! Check if all is ok!**